# Blue hues in Aluminum mirror

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, reflection, wavelength

[[image: Al mirror with no blue hue]][[image: Al mirror with blue hue]] When depositing Aluminium sometimes I end up with a bluish hue to my film especially when changing angle of view. I use a very high rate of deposition and low temperature. What would cause this?

Comment: Have you measured the thickness?  Often the appearance changes as films become thinner; most of my experience is with gold and platinum, so I only raise the question.

Comment: An image of this hue might be nice.

Comment: My pictures are not the best but you can see the hue I'm talking about. I have measured the thickness of my AL layer and it is + - 3 % of the desired thickness. At this time I will be performing calibration runs for SiO2 and TiO2 to determine better tooling factors for my Xtal readings. I have to add the TiO2 layer to enhance my reflectivity to meet spectral requirements of this mirror. The SiO2 and TiO2 layers will be deposited with ion assist using Ar/O2 mixture. I have seen browning of the AL layer before because of using to slow of a rate but this blue/purple hue is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell for sure without experimental verification, but almost for sure that this is related to optical interference due to the thickness of the film.

It would actually be expectable that such observation would occur with this type of samples. I have observed this type of colors due to interference before:

[NbO/Nb2O5 core–shells by thermal oxidation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0955221913003208)

Try to record spectra of the reflected light for different angles to verify such hypothesis.